# Manipulate: rename list position to string or number for appearance purpose

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

I have a `Table` of 5 numbers, from 10 to 50.

```
f = Table[r*y, {r, 10, 50, 10}]
```

I am plotting withint a `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[[i]], {y, 1, 5},PlotRange -> Full], {{i, 1, "value of y"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

and I get:

[image]

**What I want**:  in the iterator `i`, I have to put the value of the list element. However, what I would like is to put the actual value of `y` (the numbers from 10 to 50), so that they just show up in the Manipulate plot.

I tried replacing the `{1,2,3,4,5}` with `{10,20,30,40,50}` but it actually reads the value of the number and finds the respective element in the list, so that does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[[i]], {y, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> Full],
 {{i, 1, "value of y"}, Thread[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} -> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}]}]
```

You can also use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) on an array of values:

```
yvals = Range[10, 50, 10];
Manipulate[
 Plot[yvals[[i]]*y, {y, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> Full],
 {{i, 1, "value of y"}, MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, yvals]}]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. What about if I replacing a slider with a lot values? Can I avoid the argment of <code>Thread</code> and just call it something more compact?

Comment: @SuperCiocia The syntax is a list of `value -> label`, if the labels are different from the values (indices in this case). You can use `Thread`, `Map`, `Table` etc. to construct the list; I used `MapIndexed` in the second example. `MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, Coefficient[f, y]]` is a way to use your list `f`, but it depends on the structure of `f`, which I assumed was a toy example.  Nothing strikes me as particularly compact, because somehow you have to construct the rules.

Comment: Thank you that works - last thing though: how do I make that into a slider, while keeping the step discrete? I tried ControlType->Slider but it does not like it.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Is `Manipulate[Plot[fi, {y, 1, 5}], {{fi, First@f, "value of y"}, f, ControlType -> Slider}]` the kind of thing you want?